# Missing UPS Shipping Methods on the Magento Frontend

Tags: magento, ups

What would cause ups shipping methods that are selected in magento's shipping method admin page to not show up as shipping options to customers.  Specifically I'm trying to get the ground commercial option to show up on the frontend.

I've done some research on this, it seems like this questions been asked a before and never answered (that i can find) so I'll ask it again and throw in my research on the subject.

I've traced the source code from the shipping cost estimations in the shopping cart and found that when you enter a zip code it creates an entry in the 'sales_flat_quote_address' table with basically just the postcode and id fields filled.

It also creates rows in 'sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate'.  one for each applicable shipping method for that quote/address pair.

When magento lists the shipping options it references this table.

Somewhere between the shipping methods admin and this database table some of the shipping methods are filtered out.

I think it has something to do with residential/commercial addresses.  However ups's rating api cant determine if an address is residential/commercial if only given a zip code.  Also changing the destination type in the admin page does not have an effect on which methods are displayed on the frontend.

For reference if all ups shipping methods are selected in the back end, the following are the only ones that show up on the front end:

ground
3 Day Select
2nd Day Air
Next Day Air Saver
Next Day Air
Next Day Air Early AM

This is out of 22 options selected in the backend.

Comment: Please check minimum order amount to be aviled UPS shipping method.

Comment: Have you tried turning on logging for UPS in the admin, and checking the log? It may be an api issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Configuration from admin panel
In the Configuration panel on the left, under Sales, click Shipping Methods.
Click to expand the UPS section. Then set enable to yes.

Comment: i have same issue. but i enable it. still it does not showing